# Copy files and output the target path of the overriden files

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I would like to write a batch that will copy all of the files in a given source path to a given output path, and plot the target path of the files that were actually changed.
XCOPY is doing almost that. It plots the source paths.

I guess it would be easier with PowerShell, but I would rather keeping it in the bat file.

Comment: Do you want specifically "changed" or "changed or created" ?

Comment: o-o methods &c are overridden, files are _overwritten_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending Sumit's suggestion of the /F option - you could use FOR /F to parse out only the destination files. There is no need for a batch script. It can be a one liner on the interactive command line.

```
for /f "delims=> tokens=2" %A in ('xcopy /f "someSourcePath\*.txt" "someDestinationPath"') do @echo %A
```

The above will include an unwanted leading space on each line of output. If needed, you can use an extra FOR /F to remove the leading space.

```
for /f "delims=> tokens=2" %A in ('xcopy /f "someSourcePath\*.txt" "someDestinationPath"') do @for /f "tokens=* delims= " %B in ("%A") do @echo %B
```

Either way, the file count at the end is also removed.

Double all `%` as `%%` if you put the command in a batch script.

The solution is even simpler if you have my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - a purely script based utility (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
xcopy /F "someSourcePath\*.txt" "someDestinationPath" | jrepl "> (.*)" $1 /jmatch
```

If you want to preserve the file count at the end, then you could use an even simpler variation

```
xcopy /F "someSourcePath\*.txt" "someDestinationPath" | jrepl "^.*> " ""
```

Answer (score 2):

You can print source path and new destination path together with `F` switch in `xcopy`

Consider this example

```
xcopy * DRIVE-LETTER:\New\ /F
```

Will output in this format

```
F:\OLD-FOLDER\DSCN.JPG -> F:\New\DSCN.JPG
F:\OLD-FOLDER\DSCN1.JPG -> F:\New\DSCN1.JPG
```

Comment: Any way to get only the target path? Maybe pipeline it to another command?

Comment: Check the dbenham's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726608/copy-files-and-output-the-target-path-of-the-overriden-files/34728132#34728132) for custom output.

Answer (score 1):

This script takes two arguments: the source dir and the dest dir
It is a functional example. (You'll need to customize the output to suit your needs.) The script **does not** check for errors. You may (or may not) wish to do that.

```
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@ECHO OFF

REM

SET "SRC_PATH=%~1"
SET "DST_PATH=%~2"

MKDIR "%DST_PATH%"

REM  Copy the files
FOR %%f IN (%SRC_PATH%\*.*) DO (
    SET "SRC_FILE=%%~f"
    SET "DST_FILE=%DST_PATH%\%%~nxf"

    @ECHO SOURCE FILE: !SRC_FILE!
    @ECHO DEST FILE  : !DST_FILE!
    COPY "!SRC_FILE!" "!DST_FILE!"
)

REM  Recursively descend into the subdirectories
FOR /D %%d IN (%SRC_PATH%\*.*) DO (
    SET "SRC_SUBDIR=%%~d"
    SET "DST_SUBDIR=%DST_PATH%\%%~nxd"

    @ECHO SOURCE DIR: !SRC_SUBDIR!
    @ECHO DEST DIR  : !DST_SUBDIR!
    cmd /c %~s0 "!SRC_SUBDIR!" "!DST_SUBDIR!"
)
```

Alter the `ECHO` statements to do what you need.

Comment: This probably won't handle hidden directories.

Comment: Also, you'd have to handle the decision about whether or not to copy the file. `copy`, `xcopy`, and `robocopy` are none of them built to handle optionally copying a single file.